# Shadowrun 5e breakdown/tutorial

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun, system-introduction

Long time D&D'er, I purchased the 5th edition Shadowrun Core Rulebook.

Now I am in a bit of a pickle, as with most things when reading trough the books I usually get a gest of the rules, but I need some breakdown or spoken tutorial for all the information to crystallize in my head.

So the question is, can people help me find an easy breakdown or maybe a video tutorial of being a game master and making runs for Shadowrun.

Answer (score 10):

The first thing that comes to mind when I read this question is the [Quick Start Rules](http://cdn.shadowruntabletop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/E-CAT27QSR_SR5-Quick-Start-Rules.pdf) that they released.  This is an official and free document as far as I'm aware and should at least give you a frame for what to do.  Because this is designed for comprehension from the uninitiated the setup is a little more intuitive and a lot less spread out than the core rulebook, which is  a fairly dense volume.

As a personal note, the way I make myself accustomed to a system is through character creation.  Usually when I make a character it gives me a nice logical flow as to how it works.  The game will say "determine/pick this" and if it's not obvious, I'll start looking at the index/Table of Contents and look for a section that more satisfactorily explains the concept. Lather, rinse, repeat until the first character is made.  After that?  Make a character with a different concept.  Maybe I've started with a straightforward street samurai and now I want to look at an Adept.  Then a sorcerer.  Just sit down and take some time and work with it.  Granted, you've mentioned you're a more aural learner, which makes it difficult if you lack anyone experienced in this system.  There seem to be a few videos on YouTube of recorded play segments but I haven't watched them to link to anything with confidence.  While these aren't meant to teach the game they do provide a session in progress to get a feel.

Answer (score 1):

SomethingAbout TableTop [sic.] created a nice ~20 minute walk-through, which is [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZJD_CnMugY). He makes it simple & straightforward, & he doesn't get down in the weeds.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46274)

Comment: While I generally agree, the request was specifically for a "spoken tutorial." Doppelgreener already has the info in writing, & was looking for a way to listen to the content so that he could reinforce it in a manner better suited to his preferred learning style.